# Find a point in a complex polygon

Tags: opengl, collision-detection, polygon, hittest

This polygon could be shaped like a C

I tried the formula located here
[How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

however it doesn't actually correctly predict if the point is in the polygon.

Comment: Do you really mean complex (self intersecting) or convex ( 'C' shaped) ?

Comment: 'C' shaped polygons are not convex

Comment: Sorry meant to say concave - and you can't edit comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way - especially for lots of points is to triangulate the polygon then do a point in triangle test.
You could convert the polygon into a set of convex polygons but that is trickier.

See also [Random points inside a 4-sided Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240778/random-points-inside-a-polygon)