# Generate random lat lon

Tags: java, python, algorithm, google-maps

I need it to stress test some location based web service. The input is 4 pairs of lat/lon defining a bounding rectangle or a set of points defining a polygon.

Are there any libraries/algorithms for generating random point on a map? (Python/java)

Comment: So the polygon might not be a square/rectangle?

Comment: Yes. I would start with convex for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question, which deals with generating points inside an arbitrary 4-point convex polygon.

[Random points inside a 4-sided Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240778/random-points-inside-a-polygon)

Answer (score 3):

In java you can use Math.random()

For example, if you want to generate a random number between 1 and 10:

```
int randomNumGenerated = (int)(Math.Random()*10) + 1;
```

You can apply this to the issue you are trying to solve easily.

Comment: It's not clear how to apply this efficiently when dealing with 4 points that don't necessarily represent a rectangle.

Comment: You only need to randomly generate two points for Long and Lat e.g. (a,b) and (a,y) where x co-ordinate is the same. Then randomly generate the rectangle breadth i.e br. 3rd rectangle point is (a, b+br). 4th rectangle point is (a, y+br)

Comment: Look at the question - the randomized points should be part of a *general polygon*, not necessarily a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

This article, on [sphere point picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) explains far better than I could why the naive approach of generating 2 random numbers on the interval [0,1) will lead to a poor distribution of points across the surface of the sphere.  That may or may not be a concern of OP.

However, it ought to be of concern to OP that randomly generating a set of 4 points on the surface of the Earth might necessitate some tricky programming.  Consider the case of the 'polygon' defined by the points (lat/long, all in degrees) `(+5,90),(+5,-90),(-5,-90),(-5,90)`.  Does the point `(0,0)` lie inside this polygon or outside it ?  What about the point `(0,180)` ?  It's very easy to generate such ambiguous polygons -- the surface of a sphere is not well modelled by the Euclidean plane.

I'd take a completely different approach -- generate 1 point at random, then generate lat and long offsets.  This will give you a quasi-rectangular patch on the surface, and you can tune the generation of the offsets to avoid ambiguous polygons.  If you want to generate polygons which are not quasi-rectangular, generate a series of points and angles which, when combined, define a polygon which suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just generate the latitude as a random number between -90 and 90, and the longitude as another random number between -180 and 180?

Then you have a point. Yo can then generate as many points as you need to make a polygon.

You can generate a random number between `a` and `b` with something like:

```
rnum = a + rnd() * (b-a); // where rnd() gives a number from 0 to 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Generate two random numbers, one for latitude and one for longitude, inside the bounding rectangle of the map, for each point.

Answer (score 0):

double longitude = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;

or use

```
public static LatLng random(Random r) {            

return new LatLng((r.nextDouble() * -180.0) + 90.0,
                                (r.nextDouble() * -360.0) + 180.0);
        }
```