# Generate N random coordinates in a point delimited form using PHP

Tags: php

I believe I need a solution using PHP for the following problem. Let's start and say we have a map, that width is 100000 and height 100000.

I'd have a region into that map, designed by many X / Y / Z coordinates. something like:

`{{-56000;190073;-4509};{-54955;190073;-4509};{-54954;190638;-4509}{-56000;190638;-4509}}`

That's 4 points forming a square on our map. But the zones can be defined by 10+ points, so nothing like squares.

Now I'd need a way to generate N different random coordinates that are INSIDE that region.

I don't know where and how to start with this problem, but I know how to use PHP. Just actually lacking the theory part. What algorithm could I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random points inside a Polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240778/random-points-inside-a-polygon)

Comment: @nicolascolman That's 4 years old... And no, I did not want to create zones, I was asking to create random points inside a defined zone

Comment: I will try to close this question as a duplicate of the suggested link above.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function to generate x & y coordinates n the range specified by your bounds:

```
$x = rand($min_x, $max_x);
$y = rand($min_y, $max_y);
```

I'm not sure what range you want to use for your z coordinate.

Comment: (in the instance of the OP all z coordinates are identical and need not to be randomized)

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks. Although looking at the OP's question again, the coordinates listed do not quite form a square :-S

Comment: Perhaps it's a skewed/rotated square rather than an exact square? If that's the case there's quite a bit more geometry involved in this question than I originally thought.

Comment: Yes... I think it's a typo though. I'm going to assume it's a typo.

Comment: Nope it's not, zones can be whatever form they need to be, the exemple was just an exemple, but imagine a star per exemple?

Comment: @Psychokiller1888 There's a **huge** difference between finding a random point in a polygon and a random point in a regular square. Perhaps you're looking for [Random points inside a Polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240778/random-points-inside-a-polygon)?

Comment: Yes, it's inside a polygone, we can drop the third dimension. It can be in a square, but can be a polygon too. I'll take a look to your link, thank you